# Abstract Django model doesn't have a "model" attribute?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have an abstract model in a Django app:

```
class HistoryTrackedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.model, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the real save method
        # Do some miscellaneous work here (after saving)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

A child model uses the abstract model as its base:

```
class Project(HistoryTrackedModel):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=False, db_index=True)
    ... other fields ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

When I instantiate an instance of Project (the child model), and call the `save()` method, I get the following error:

> 'Project' object has no attribute 'model'

It's failing on the `super(self.model, self).save()` call in the abstract class's save method. I attempted to change that method to the following, but it (fairly obviously, now that I look at it) gets caught in a recursive loop:

```
class HistoryTrackedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_model = type(self)
        super(my_model, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the real save method
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't all child classes that inherit from a base class (which itself inherits from models.Model) include the `model` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
super(HistoryTrackedModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

should work.